# Rotation of co-ordiante axes for a cubic crystal: Matrix rotation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, rotations, crystallography

When carrying out a rotation of the co-ordinate axes, x1 x2 x3 to say x1' x2' x3',

When dealinf with the rotation of axes about a vector (using an orthogonal rotation matrix R), I was taught to use V' = R.V BUT for a matrix I should use M' = R.M.R^T    (where R^-1 = R^T)

However, if my matrix is say M =

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I.e. a crystal with unit vectors: V1 $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
 V2 $$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

V3 $$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrti4.png)
Then this obviously does not work as it just takes me back tot he original identity rather than rotating my matrix. So, is the identity matrix an exception here i.e. should I use M'=R.M only when my matrix is the identity and use M'=R.M.R^T when it is some other matrix e.g. if my crystal took different unit vecors like M = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 5 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
This is really confusing me.

Comment: When $M=I$ what makes you think that $M'$ shouldn’t also be the identity matrix? What exactly do these matrices represent?

Comment: A unit cube. The 3 columns represent the unti vectors [100], [010] and [001]

Comment: Example image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_cube

Comment: That doesn’t really help. “Transforming a matrix” with no other context isn’t well-defined. Matrices can represent many different types of objects, and those objects all have different transformation rules. The one you cite is applicable to matrices that represent linear transformations, but not, say, to matrices that represent quadratic forms. It looks like the matrices that you’re talking about are just a representation of a set of vectors, so they should transform whatever way those vectors would.